# How to execute a sql file

Tags: database, postgresql, go

I have .sql file which has lots of database creation, deletion, population stuff. Is it possible to have a go function which can excute a sql file. I am using postgres as my database and using lib/pq driver for all database transactions. But I am open to any library for executing this sql file in my Go project.

Answer (score 22):

It's too much trouble if you are going to execute it using a command line. You have to deal with issues like setting your passwords, making sure the path variables are properly set, etc. I think the bets way is to use the database driver and just call it using Go.

In the following example, I'm using [pgx implementation of sql driver](https://godoc.org/github.com/jackc/pgx) for Postgres. You can do it with any driver implementation of your choice.

```
path := filepath.Join("path", "to", "script.sql")

c, ioErr := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
if ioErr != nil {
   // handle error.
}
sql := string(c)
_, err := *pgx.Conn.Exec(sql)
if err != nil {
  // handle error.
}
```

Explanation:

1. Get the path to your sql script in a os agnostic way.
2. Read the content of the file to string.
3. Execute the statements in the file using the sql driver.

Comment: MUST add `?multiStatements=true` in your connection string or  you'll get `You have an error in your SQL syntax`

Comment: now that `ioutil` is deprecated it's better to use `os.Readfile`

Answer (score 10):

You can just split file into separate requests and execute them one-by-one:

```
file, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/some/path/to/file")

if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

requests := strings.Split(string(file), ";")

for _, request := range requests {
    result, err := db.Exec(request)
    // do whatever you need with result and error
}
```

Comment: It won't work if you have procedures in you sql file.

Comment: `requests := strings.Split(string(file), ";") ` will break in case of SQL like this: `INSERT INTO testtable(test) VALUES('abc;def');`

Comment: Suggest using `strings.Split(string(file), ";\n")` to avoid the problem that @GeneS mentioned.

Comment: `";\n"` also works for `panic: Error 1065: Query was empty ` error

Comment: This won't work if you have triggers with PLpgSQL, since it would need to parse the BEGIN and END, etc...

Answer (score 10):

I found dotsql in search of similar demand. You can load named sql statements/prepare statements from a specific file and execute.

```
// Get a database handle
db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", ":memory:")

// Loads queries from file
dot, err := dotsql.LoadFromFile("queries.sql")

// Run queries
res, err := dot.Exec(db, "create-users-table")
res, err := dot.Exec(db, "create-user", "User Name", "main@example.com")
rows, err := dot.Query(db, "find-users-by-email", "main@example.com")
row, err := dot.QueryRow(db, "find-one-user-by-email", "user@example.com")

stmt, err := dot.Prepare(db, "drop-users-table")
result, err := stmt.Exec()
```

see: https://github.com/gchaincl/dotsql

Answer (score 9):

You can use `os/exec` package of standard library. No database driver is required. Code would look something like this for postgreSQL:

```
cmd := exec.Command("psql", "-U", psqlUser, "-h", psqlHost, "-d", psqlDBName, "-a", "-f", sqlFilePath)

var out, stderr bytes.Buffer

cmd.Stdout = &out
cmd.Stderr = &stderr

err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error executing query. Command Output: %+v\n: %+v, %v", out.String(), stderr.String(), err)
}
```

Comment: prerequisite is `psql` tool installed.

Answer (score 5):

#### Here you have 2 options:

1. Using sql driver to connect to db and execute the sql statements:
   Here a full example using additionally transaction:

   ```
   func loadSQLFile(db *sqlx.DB, sqlFile string) error {
     file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(sqlFile)
     if err != nil {
         return err
     }
     tx, err := db.Begin()
     if err != nil {
         return err
     }
     defer func() {
        tx.Rollback()
     }()
     for _, q := range strings.Split(string(file), ";") {
         q := strings.TrimSpace(q)
         if q == "" {
            continue
         }
        if _, err := tx.Exec(q); err != nil {
            return err
        }
     }
     return tx.Commit()
   }
   ```

usage:

```
loadSQLFile(db, "data/my_file.sql")
```

2. Second options by executing a bash command:

   ```
   func loadSQLFile(db, user, host, sqlFile string) error {
     cmd := exec.Command("psql", "-U", user, "-h", host, "-d", db, "-a", "-q", "-f", sqlFile)
     cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
     cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
     return cmd.Run()
   }
   ```

usage:

```
loadSQLFile("my_db", "my_user", "localhost", "data/my_file.sql")
```

While second option looks easier and shorter I recommend the first option, it gives you more control on what you do and most importantly it's more portable.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
func loadSqlFile(db *sqlx.DB) {
    // Read file
    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./test/mock.sql")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

    // Execute all
    _, err = db.Exec(string(file))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
}
```